# Matplotlib basemap toolkit install issue

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I'm having a really hard time installing Matplotlib Basemap toolkit can anyone help me with this...

I've followed these instructions:

```
basemap-1.x.x $cd geos-3.3.3
basemap-1.x.x/geos-3.3.3$ export GEOS_DIR=~/
basemap-1.x.x/geos-3.3.3 $./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
basemap-1.x.x/geos-3.3.3 $make
basemap-1.x.x/geos-3.3.3$ make install

Now you need to change back to the basemap parent directory, and install basemap:

basemap-1.x.x/geos-3.3.3 $cd ..
basemap-1.x.x$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Everything has worked except the last line... to which I get the error message

```
ceciljames101@cecilLaptop:~/basemap-1.0.7$ sudo python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is setup.py a file that should be in the directory? or is this an install on my system that is wrong? any suggestions would be appreciated

these are the only files in the basemap directory:

```
API_CHANGES  Changelog  doc  examples  FAQ  geos-3.3.3  KNOWN_BUGS  lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit the [Matplotlib Basemap Toolkit User’s Guide](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) webpage. In the Matplotlib Basemap Toolkit User’s Guide under the **Installation** heading, the first paragraph says: *Download either Windows binary installers or source tarballs [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/).* Follow the download link and download the basemap-1.0.7 file that is compatible with your operating system.

Open the basemap-1.0.7 archive and you will find the setup.py Python script for basemap-1.0.7 in the basemap-1.0.7 directory as it is marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Linux user then use following commands-

# Assuming that numpy, python3 and matplotlib is already installed.

`sudo apt-get install proj-bin
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
sudo pip3 install --user https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip`